# Disable geocoding for contacts but not for events

Tags: civievent, geocoding

Is it possible to disable geocoding for contacts but still use it for events?

I am working with an organisation that has data protection concerns about sending their beneficiaries contact details to Google or Yahoo for geocoding so they would like this option turned off for contacts.  However, it would be useful to have geocoding enabled for events so that the event page can show the location on a map.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think geocoding like this is an all or nothing thing. You can manually add the lat/long to an event location, so assuming that you don't have a whole lot of events, this should be pretty much acceptable (and just leave geocoding turned off).

With that said, no real contact details are shared with Google/Yahoo. A street address is simply sent to the geocoder without any names, or anything, and the lat/long is returned. No personally identifiable info is shared.